# Treating multiple Dichotomies combined?

Tags: logistic, classification, modeling, generative-models

Let's say I am interested in choosing a new country $c_1, \ldots, c_k$ to live in. For some reason I can only apply to one country and only once.

I know for each country a set of 2000 observations (persons), each consisting of 20 attributes and for each I know whether they were accepted or rejected. (I also know my values for each of those attributes.)

My two questions are:

1) I am not sure wether to estimate the probability distribution for acceptance/rejection independently for each country, or not. The motivation for combining observations (or parts of it) of different countries might be that countries probably have similar guidelines for rejection (for example for a convict).

2) Given the training size (2000) and the number of dimensions (20), would a discriminative model (logistic regression,... ) be appropriate or would the amount of data be enough for a generative model like (Naive Bayes). Or would any other approach might be right?

I of course just made this example up to make my question less abstract.